# MySQL - how to determine list of days of any given month

Tags: mysql, calendar, days

is there a MySQL select of function to have the list days of any given month?

**Update**

I need to have something like this list:

```
|day|
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
|.  |
|.  |
|30 |
|31 |
```

Comment: read **[this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#id2691432)** and try to find out the solution. If you get stucked, ask for help...

Comment: Thanks, I have already read it...

Comment: ok, then show us the query that you have tried and where you have stucked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure MySQL solution to generate the Query String to Make the List of Days

```
SET @GivenDate = '2012-02-26';
SELECT DAY(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt28 + INTERVAL 4 DAY,
'%Y-%m'),'-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY) - 27 INTO @DaysAfter27
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y-%m'),'-28') dt28
FROM (SELECT @GivenDate dt) AA) A;
SELECT ELT(@DaysAfter27,' UNION (SELECT 28)',
' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29)',
' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29) UNION (SELECT 30)',
' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29) UNION (SELECT 30) UNION (SELECT 31)')
INTO @DaysEndOfList;
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM',
' ((SELECT 1 Days) UNION (SELECT 2) UNION (SELECT 3)'
' UNION (SELECT  4) UNION (SELECT  5) UNION (SELECT  6)',
' UNION (SELECT  7) UNION (SELECT  8) UNION (SELECT  9)',
' UNION (SELECT 10) UNION (SELECT 11) UNION (SELECT 12)',
' UNION (SELECT 13) UNION (SELECT 14) UNION (SELECT 15)',
' UNION (SELECT 16) UNION (SELECT 17) UNION (SELECT 18)',
' UNION (SELECT 19) UNION (SELECT 20) UNION (SELECT 21)',
' UNION (SELECT 22) UNION (SELECT 23) UNION (SELECT 24)',
' UNION (SELECT 25) UNION (SELECT 26) UNION (SELECT 27)',
@DaysEndOfList,') A') INTO @DaysQuery;
PREPARE s1 FROM @DaysQuery;
EXECUTE s1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
```

Just set @GivenDate with any date you like

Here are four examples where I set @GivenDate and Execute It

## EXAMPLE 1 : 2012-02-26

```
mysql> SET @GivenDate = '2012-02-26';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DAY(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt28 + INTERVAL 4 DAY,
    -> '%Y-%m'),'-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY) - 27 INTO @DaysAfter27
    -> FROM (SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y-%m'),'-28') dt28
    -> FROM (SELECT @GivenDate dt) AA) A;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT ELT(@DaysAfter27,' UNION (SELECT 28)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29) UNION (SELECT 30)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29) UNION (SELECT 30) UNION (SELECT 31)')
    -> INTO @DaysEndOfList;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM',
    -> ' ((SELECT 1 Days) UNION (SELECT 2) UNION (SELECT 3)'
    -> ' UNION (SELECT  4) UNION (SELECT  5) UNION (SELECT  6)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT  7) UNION (SELECT  8) UNION (SELECT  9)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 10) UNION (SELECT 11) UNION (SELECT 12)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 13) UNION (SELECT 14) UNION (SELECT 15)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 16) UNION (SELECT 17) UNION (SELECT 18)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 19) UNION (SELECT 20) UNION (SELECT 21)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 22) UNION (SELECT 23) UNION (SELECT 24)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 25) UNION (SELECT 26) UNION (SELECT 27)',
    -> @DaysEndOfList,') A') INTO @DaysQuery;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE s1 FROM @DaysQuery;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE s1;
+------+
| Days |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    8 |
|    9 |
|   10 |
|   11 |
|   12 |
|   13 |
|   14 |
|   15 |
|   16 |
|   17 |
|   18 |
|   19 |
|   20 |
|   21 |
|   22 |
|   23 |
|   24 |
|   25 |
|   26 |
|   27 |
|   28 |
|   29 |
+------+
29 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## EXAMPLE 2 : 2011-02-26

```
mysql> SET @GivenDate = '2011-02-26';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DAY(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt28 + INTERVAL 4 DAY,
    -> '%Y-%m'),'-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY) - 27 INTO @DaysAfter27
    -> FROM (SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y-%m'),'-28') dt28
    -> FROM (SELECT @GivenDate dt) AA) A;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT ELT(@DaysAfter27,' UNION (SELECT 28)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29) UNION (SELECT 30)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29) UNION (SELECT 30) UNION (SELECT 31)')
    -> INTO @DaysEndOfList;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM',
    -> ' ((SELECT 1 Days) UNION (SELECT 2) UNION (SELECT 3)'
    -> ' UNION (SELECT  4) UNION (SELECT  5) UNION (SELECT  6)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT  7) UNION (SELECT  8) UNION (SELECT  9)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 10) UNION (SELECT 11) UNION (SELECT 12)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 13) UNION (SELECT 14) UNION (SELECT 15)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 16) UNION (SELECT 17) UNION (SELECT 18)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 19) UNION (SELECT 20) UNION (SELECT 21)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 22) UNION (SELECT 23) UNION (SELECT 24)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 25) UNION (SELECT 26) UNION (SELECT 27)',
    -> @DaysEndOfList,') A') INTO @DaysQuery;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE s1 FROM @DaysQuery;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE s1;
+------+
| Days |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    8 |
|    9 |
|   10 |
|   11 |
|   12 |
|   13 |
|   14 |
|   15 |
|   16 |
|   17 |
|   18 |
|   19 |
|   20 |
|   21 |
|   22 |
|   23 |
|   24 |
|   25 |
|   26 |
|   27 |
|   28 |
+------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

## EXAMPLE 3 : Today (2012-07-11)

```
mysql> SET @GivenDate = DATE(NOW());
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DAY(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt28 + INTERVAL 4 DAY,
    -> '%Y-%m'),'-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY) - 27 INTO @DaysAfter27
    -> FROM (SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y-%m'),'-28') dt28
    -> FROM (SELECT @GivenDate dt) AA) A;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT ELT(@DaysAfter27,' UNION (SELECT 28)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29) UNION (SELECT 30)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29) UNION (SELECT 30) UNION (SELECT 31)')
    -> INTO @DaysEndOfList;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM',
    -> ' ((SELECT 1 Days) UNION (SELECT 2) UNION (SELECT 3)'
    -> ' UNION (SELECT  4) UNION (SELECT  5) UNION (SELECT  6)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT  7) UNION (SELECT  8) UNION (SELECT  9)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 10) UNION (SELECT 11) UNION (SELECT 12)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 13) UNION (SELECT 14) UNION (SELECT 15)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 16) UNION (SELECT 17) UNION (SELECT 18)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 19) UNION (SELECT 20) UNION (SELECT 21)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 22) UNION (SELECT 23) UNION (SELECT 24)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 25) UNION (SELECT 26) UNION (SELECT 27)',
    -> @DaysEndOfList,') A') INTO @DaysQuery;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE s1 FROM @DaysQuery;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE s1;
+------+
| Days |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    8 |
|    9 |
|   10 |
|   11 |
|   12 |
|   13 |
|   14 |
|   15 |
|   16 |
|   17 |
|   18 |
|   19 |
|   20 |
|   21 |
|   22 |
|   23 |
|   24 |
|   25 |
|   26 |
|   27 |
|   28 |
|   29 |
|   30 |
|   31 |
+------+
31 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## EXAMPLE 4 : 2012-06-26:

```
mysql> SET @GivenDate = '2012-06-26';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DAY(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt28 + INTERVAL 4 DAY,
    -> '%Y-%m'),'-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY) - 27 INTO @DaysAfter27
    -> FROM (SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y-%m'),'-28') dt28
    -> FROM (SELECT @GivenDate dt) AA) A;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT ELT(@DaysAfter27,' UNION (SELECT 28)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29) UNION (SELECT 30)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 28) UNION (SELECT 29) UNION (SELECT 30) UNION (SELECT 31)')
    -> INTO @DaysEndOfList;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM',
    -> ' ((SELECT 1 Days) UNION (SELECT 2) UNION (SELECT 3)'
    -> ' UNION (SELECT  4) UNION (SELECT  5) UNION (SELECT  6)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT  7) UNION (SELECT  8) UNION (SELECT  9)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 10) UNION (SELECT 11) UNION (SELECT 12)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 13) UNION (SELECT 14) UNION (SELECT 15)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 16) UNION (SELECT 17) UNION (SELECT 18)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 19) UNION (SELECT 20) UNION (SELECT 21)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 22) UNION (SELECT 23) UNION (SELECT 24)',
    -> ' UNION (SELECT 25) UNION (SELECT 26) UNION (SELECT 27)',
    -> @DaysEndOfList,') A') INTO @DaysQuery;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE s1 FROM @DaysQuery;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE s1;
+------+
| Days |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    8 |
|    9 |
|   10 |
|   11 |
|   12 |
|   13 |
|   14 |
|   15 |
|   16 |
|   17 |
|   18 |
|   19 |
|   20 |
|   21 |
|   22 |
|   23 |
|   24 |
|   25 |
|   26 |
|   27 |
|   28 |
|   29 |
|   30 |
+------+
30 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `LAST_DAY('0000-00-00')`, and from your prefered language (PHP/ASP/WHATEVER) loop from last day to first.

`LAST_DAY()`

> Takes a date or datetime value and returns the corresponding value for
>   the last day of the month

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day

Comment: let OP first try by himself. SO is not just to help. Let OP try and see what he can learn. SPOON FEEDING is not good.

Comment: DAY(LAST_DAY()) give you just 31

Comment: This is one motive I have not put codes on my answer. I showed him only the direction.

Comment: @PugganSe : If I say last date of this month is 31 then obviously you will say that in this month there are 31 days. ANY DOUBT?

Comment: @PugganSe `DAY(LAST_DAY())` do the same what `LAST_DAY()`, but with ambiguous use of `DAY()`

Comment: @GabrielSantos no, `LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE())` = '2012-07-31', and `DAY(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()))` = 31

Comment: @PugganSe You don´t understand-me. These mysql functions does the same in my answer's context, because I need to do a loop from the last day (or number) to the first.

Comment: thanks for the help. Actually LAST_DAY() returns only the last day of month, I need to the entire list of days.

Comment: @freedev see `explode` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), or Puggan Se' tip.

Answer (score -1):

i have a table named range that contains all integers from 0 up to about 100.
its useful for querys like this:

```
SELECT '2012-07-01' + INTERVAL nr day AS day 
FROM test.range 
WHERE nr < 32 
HAVING MONTH(day) = MONTH('2012-07-01');
```